# 画面ロック時にPCが操作不能になり，起動すると Time-of-day not set - please run SETUP program と言われる

Tags: bios

### 問題の要約

#### 環境

まず，私の環境を書きます．

| メーカ | OS |
| --- | --- |
| Dell | Windows10 Pro |

#### 問題の詳しい説明

問題ですが，タイトルの通りです．`Windows + L` で画面をロックした際に，常にではありませんがたまに，PCの画面がまっくらになり，一切のキー操作を受け付けなくなることがあります．

`ctrl + alt + del` しても反応なし．電源ボタンを連打しても反応なし．

厳密には「一切のキー操作」ではなく，電源ボタンを長押ししたときだけ反応があります．capslock キーが点灯するのです．なぜ点灯するのか，それが何を意味するのかは調べてもよくわかりませんでした．

電源ボタンの長押しを繰り返していると，やがて起動します．

電源コードが抜けていてバッテリが切れてしまった時にそっくりなのですが，電源コードはきちんと刺さっておりバッテリにも問題ないようです．

#### エラーメッセージ

電源ボタンを長押しすることを繰り返していると，起動することには成功しますが，エラーメッセージが出ます．エラーメッセージの内容はさまざまで，

> Windows が読み込めませんでした

と言われることもあれば，

> Time-of-day not set - please run SETUP program.
>
> Invalid configuration information - please run SETUP program.

と言われることもあります．

### 試したこと

- Windows のアップデートは行いました．
- Dell のサポートページから BIOS のアップデートを行いました．
- Intel のグラフィックドライバの再インストールを行いました．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのエラーメッセージは，おそらく電源ボタンを長押ししているために，[RTCリセット](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000125880/how-to-reset-real-time-clock-rtc-to-recover-your-dell-portable-system)がかかったからだと思います．

電源ボタンを25秒以上長押しすると，RTCリセットが起こります．

ファンクションキー `Fn` と電源ボタンを同時に長押しして起動するとハードウェアのテストが行われますが，それを途中で抜けて起動すればエラーメッセージを出さずに起動することはできそうです．

依然として原因は不明ですし，直すこともできていませんが．

Comment: この質問は StackOverflow ではなく Windowsフォーラムに投稿すべきだったかもしれません